# Как создать подсети для каждой отдельной связки docker compose?

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Всем доброго времени суток!

Я на данный момент изучаю докер для быстрого свертывания \ развертывания проектов на сервере\локалке для разарботки, и столкнулся с проблемой.

Я придумал немного странную композицию, в качестве фронта у меня NGINX который по идее должен проксировать все запросы по разным "связкам" docker-compose (т.е связке контейнеров)

Это связанно с тем что проект A у меня может быть php-apache + mysql, второй java+tomcat+SQLite.

Я в принципе уже сам разобрался как сделать такую композицию, но то решение которое у меня сейчас не очень удобное
На данный момент я создаю общую сеть для всех рабочих контейнеров, но из за этого у меня возникаю коллизии портов

т.е у меня это выглядит так:

1. Запускается отдельно контейнер NGINX на порте 8080
2. Далее я запускаю свой проект, в котором apache+mysql+php в той же сети что и контейнер с докером
   Из за чего мне нужно вручную прописывать порты внутри каждого отдельного проекта. Это не совсем то что нужно, ведь основная цель что бы проекты были максимально независимы и не связаны конфигом

Нету ли в линукс\nginx\docker способа создать что то вроде виртуальной подсети для каждоого проекта, и потом обращаться к этой сети через NGINX по локальному DNS?

например назвать сеть проекта А: project_a
в NGINX проксировать запрос на project_a:80 (внутри сети у apache прокинуть порт 80)
с проектом б тоже самое

Мою бы проблему решило бы так же "запекание" связки контейнеров docker-compose в один образ, но гугление показало что это противоречит цели docker-compose (организации контейнеров докер)

Comment: Не совсем понятно. У вас все образы в одном проекте? Если да, проксируйте из него только один контейнер на :80, остальные могут общаться друг с другом по имени сервиса внутри одного проекта `http://service_name`

Comment: Приложите пример docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose лучше применять для каждого проекта отдельно -- раздельный деплой, т. к. некоторые проекты (которые просто паботают) не хочется трогать во время деплоя других.

Можно написать небольшую обертку к docker-compose которая может, например:

- вывести лист используемых портов
- проверить конфликты портов
- создать конечные yml по шаблонам

---

Можно создать подсети, но есть шанс, что при рестарте сервера докер запутается и не сможет поднять все это в нужном порядке.